# Saltstack mode for emacs

Tags: python, emacs, salt-stack

How can I get Emacs to work with Salt files?  Is there some code already available, or how can I create a mode myself?

There's a [Sublime Text plugin](https://github.com/saltstack/sublime-text/) that does something similar.

Thanks

Comment: Is a request for a an emacs mode really that subjective or subject to opinionated answwers?  It seems there is an emacs mode, or there isn't.  Notice that the question didn't ask how good it was, and both answers were helpful (phils more so than mine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sublime text config you linked to [appears](https://github.com/saltstack/sublime-text/blob/master/YAML.sublime-settings) to just use a YAML mode, so you could do the same thing using the [yaml-mode](https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode) available for Emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sls\\'" . yaml-mode))
```

or if you wanted to incorporate the tab settings from that sublime config, you could create a new mode like so:

```el
(require 'yaml-mode)

(define-derived-mode saltstack-mode yaml-mode "Saltstack"
  "Minimal Saltstack mode, based on `yaml-mode'."
  (setq tab-width 2
        indent-tabs-mode nil))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sls\\'" . saltstack-mode))
```

(n.b. untested)

Comment: Thanks, I put this together so I could use parts of both of your ideas: https://gist.github.com/tbonza/20757551443a61254aa6

Comment: There is also a [jinja2 mode](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/jinja2-mode) available.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem so -- though I did find a formula for using saltstack to install emacs....

https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/emacs-formula

It looks like salt supports provisioning editors, but they figure that their use of jinja-templates in Pillar makes things easy enough.